# Where to start the books when you are watching the series?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

As someone who likes fantasy, I got hooked recently on the *Game Of Thrones* TV Show. I've watched all episodes so far :

> Joffrey is dead, Sansa is at her Aunt's caslte, Daenerys is doing her thing (save all the slaves!) and Jon and Bran almost met in the North)

I really would like to read the books from now on. However, I have understood that the story implementation in the book is quite complex (If I'm not mistaken, at some point the story is told from one character's point of view to another). I'm someone who gets really bored when I "redo" something so I want to avoid as much as possible to read events that have already happened in the TV Show. Is it possible and if yes where do I start reading?

If it has any importance, I'm not really worried about the minor differences between the book and the TV Show.

Comment: It's a bit difficult, because where we're at in the series is split over two books. And those two books story lines occur in parallel, whilst the TV series is combining those two books to occur in chronological order. The long and short of it is that you'll read stuff that you've already seen

Comment: The first 3 books are the ones that are easiest to read and most action packed, and the last two the slowest. I don't know if there really is any point in reading those last two unless you know the back story in books 1-3. I think it will be quite a strange experience. In my opinion, the first 3 books are quite a lot better than the last two. You would be starting at the middle/end of book 3, beginning of book 4, depending on which story arch you follow. (Although some events in book 5 are also in the show)

Comment: I agree with @TLP. This is probably opinion based.

Comment: @TLP I see, I guess it might just be best to start from scratch then.

Comment: @WizLiz I would either not read any books, or read them all. It would be interesting to hear your opinion as to how that worked out afterwards. You should know that there are a lot more mysteries and back stories in the books. Such as: Who Jon Snow's mother is.

Comment: Start from the beginning, the only way to start any kind of series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, each book chapter is told from the point of view of one of the characters. The story is complex and has diverged from the books so if you want to do the story justice you really should read the books starting from the beginning.

However, you might be able to get away with skipping the first book, Game of Thrones, and starting with book 2, A Clash of Kings. Although you will miss a lot of the story - especially the finer details - the first season of the TV show stayed very true to the book, so you shouldn't be lost.